# How to prevent XSS attack in my function?

Tags: php, sql-injection, xss

I am creating a function for my `$_POST` inputs to prevent SQL Injection BEFORE adding the values into database. I use it on login/register and when a user needs to post an article. As far as I know, this does not secure it from XSS.

Should I create a different function when I output data or edit this?

Thank you.

```
function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string for protection when storing in mysql db. doesn't remove html and js.  striptags, advanced preg_replace pattern and/or htmlentities should help .

Comment: take a look at this: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Dreaded semicolon - `Htmlentities` on input and `htmlspecialchars` on output right ?

Comment: prepared statements for sql injections & `htmlspecialchars` the output, plus use of type checking...

Comment: no. I personally prefer to purify texts when printing . on input to database use mysql_real_escape_string.   on output you can use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars + striptags. you can centralize it in a class or function, so you can change it or tweak it easily. htmlentities convert more entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using prepared statements. They are designed to automatically escape things. They should also keep your queries cleaner in the source code.

- http://www.ultramegatech.com/blog/2009/07/using-mysql-prepared-statements-in-php/
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Strictly speaking, they don't actually escape the strings, because they don't actually build a raw SQL query with them. The query, with the placeholders, is sent as-is to the database, and the values are sent separately. With prepared statements, there's no need to escape anything.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm using http://adodb.sourceforge.net/ and for nonsupporting databases & drivers it tries to do the escaping itself... the end result is basically the same from the programmer's perspective

Answer (score 3):

You talk about XSS and then SQL injection...

#### SQL

Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or better still bind params with a library such as PDO.

If `magic_quotes` is a possibility, use...

```
function sqlEscape($str) {
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $str = stripslashes($str);
   }
   return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

Regarding your example, why do you need to use `trim()` to make data safe? Also, why use the error supressor on `trim()`?

#### XSS

Use `htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES)` to prevent HTML special characters from having special meaning.

Comment: Why shouldn't `trim` the data?

Comment: @Nikolai It is just irrelevant to escaping data in a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following, which works just fine to prevent injections:

```
function clean($str) {
    $value = mysql_escape_string(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($str)));
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this... Why did you leave outside magic_quotes? Is it as unnecessary as they say ?

Comment: magic_quotes is slowly dying, and deprecated since 5.3. I personally don't consider them anymore when coding (but I don't use shared hosting either, so I have full control over the configuration). I would just set an `php_flag` in your `.htaccess` to disable it. The only reason to do it the way you did is to support shared hosting with PHP <5.3, that enables magic_quotes it by default and don't let you use `.htaccess` files, which isn't very common

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't save values as encoded HTML to your database. Do that when outputting them, not when saving them (saving encoded HTML makes it harder to search in it, makes their size bigger, makes it harder to use them in formats other than HTML and generally just wrong - your database should store the actual text, not the text formatted to be displayed in a specific way).

Also, as Quamis said, you should probably look at PDO or some other DBAL that lets you use prepared statements instead of escaping it manually.